# read_csv naming the resulted dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to read some CSVs from a given directory and I want to name the resulted dataframes similarly to the name of the csv.
So I wrote the code bellow but I am aware that it is not the rigth syntax. 
Beside I have the error :

```
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

My code :

```
import os    
for element in os.listdir('.'):
        element[:-4] = read_csv(element)
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Put your dataframes in a dictionary? `dfs = {}` then `for element in os.listdir('.'): dfs[element[:-4]] = pd.read_csv(element)` ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. it is a great idea but I still should access the dataframes by dfs["element1"] ... Is there another way to have directely element1 = DataFrame(element1). Thank you

Comment: If it doesn't exist or it is difficult I will use the dictionaries. Thank you.

Comment: Yes - but you won't know what variables to use without getting the directory listing again... if you stick with a dictionary - at least all your dataframes are contained in a single place and you can use the keys as the names and the values as the dataframes... You *really* don't want to go down the route of dynamic variables... (not to mention what to do if element[:-4] yields something that isn't valid Python syntax for a name - you'll never be able to access it as you wish...)

Comment: Ok thank you @JonClements

Answer (score 0):

you can do that by add tempering the global scope as follows:

```
import os
for i in os.listdir('.'):
    globals()[i] = pd.read_csv(i)
```

But, that's very ugly and, as @JonClements pointed out, won't work if the filename doesn't follow the python variable naming rules. As a reminder, variable naming rules are :

```
Variables names must start with a letter or an underscore, such as:
_underscore
underscore_
The remainder of your variable name may consist of letters, numbers and underscores.
password1
n00b
un_der_scores
```

check this [link](https://thehelloworldprogram.com/python/python-variable-assignment-statements-rules-conventions-naming/) for more explanation.

---

The best way is to create a dictionary:

```
import os
d = {}
for i in os.listdir('.'):
    d[i] = pd.read_csv(i)
```

Then you can access any dataframe you want as follows `d['file1.csv']`

Comment: Not just ugly... What if your filename is `some-file` - try and get that back to use :) (outside of the general case of knowing which variables you've shoved into globals that are dataframes and which ones aren't...)

Comment: And one might as well dict-comp this anyway: `dfs = {fname[:-4]: pd.read_csv(fname) for fname in os.listdir('.')` etc...

Comment: @JonClements, yes you are right. I updated my answer to point out that it won't work when the variable name doesn't follow python's convention. Thanks.

Comment: Well, the thing is - since `globals()` is a `dict`, you can make it contain variables that don't meet the syntax `globals()['some-file'] = 'abc'` *will* work... But you can't access it as `some-file` as a name any more unless you access it via `globals()` again...

Comment: @JonClements, yes that's what I wanted to say, `globals()['hello'] = "world";print(hello)` works whereas `globals()['some-file'] = "world";print(some-file)` doesn't.

Comment: @MedAli well, unless you had a variable `some = 5` and another `file = 3` - then you'd get `2` :p

Comment: @JonClements oops, it's quite a mess ! Better not use it :D

Comment: @JonClements, I recommend that you put an answer, so I vote it up :)

Comment: @MedAli nope you're fine - just wanted to point out that if you're writing to `globals()` you need a *very, very good reason* and understand why you're doing it. This isn't one. Just spreading the word :)

Comment: @JonClements, I never do that, but thanks for spreading the word :)